# NSUserDefaults vs. NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, data-structures

I think this is a beginner's question about data management.

I have an app which loads and saves different txt files. I would like to give each txt file certain characteristics which are not saved in the txt file, such as name, style, colour etc.

What I did so far was to have a NSMutableArray *myLibrary where I would save all these references. The array looks like this:

- for each txt file one object is added to myLibrary
- each object holds several NSStrings, NSUInteger, BOOLs, and some NSMutableArrays
- in my subclass for these objects, I work with

  -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
  -(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;

Now, my **big question** is what the best and *safest* way is to persevere this data. So far, I've worked with NSKeyedArchiver, but users have reported data loss and there has been one weird case in which the iTunes sync allegedly caused data to be messed up. Is NSUserDefaults any saver? I am saving the myLibrary.dat every time the user has made a change, so I don't really understand why it shouldn't be 100% save. Any advice / suggestions / explanations would be very much appreciated!

Here is the code with which I write and read myLibrary.Dat:

```
   -(NSString*)documentsDirectory
{
    NSLog(@"documentsDirectory");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory
    return documentsDirectory;
}

-(void)saveLibraryDat {

    NSLog(@"Saving myLibrary.dat...");
    NSString *filePath = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myLibrary.dat"];
    BOOL succeed = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myLibrary] writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    if (!succeed){ // do something  }

}


-(void)loadLibraryDat {

    NSLog(@"loadLibraryDat");
    NSString *filePath = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myLibrary.dat"];

    self.myLibrary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];

    if (self.myLibrary == nil) {
        NSLog(@"myLibrary.dat empty... set up new one");
        [self setupLibrary];
    } else { NSLog(@"Loading myLibrary.dat successful."); }

}
```

---

EDIT: My coder methods look like this:

```
 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.titleName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"titleName"];
        self.fileName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"fileName"];
        self.fileFont = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"fileFont"];
 self.tabTitles = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tabTitles"];
   }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:titleName forKey:@"titleName"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:fileName forKey:@"fileName"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:fileFont forKey:@"fileFont"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:tabTitles forKey:@"tabTitles"];
}

@end
```

in the header these are defined as:

```
NSString *titleName;
NSString *fileName;
NSString *fileFont;
NSMutableArray *tabTitles;
```

Comment: Those four member variables are of what type? NSString*?

Comment: @Matthieu Cormier: sorry, they are NSStrings and NSMutableArrays. I also have BOOL, NSUInteger, but didn't want to include them here to make it less convoluted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't user NSUserDefaults.  It is more for default settings like should I display window X on startup.  NSUserDefaults is not designed for program data.  You should be using NSKeyArchiver as you are doing.  The bug is most likely in the objects that myLibrary contains.

You should take a look at(or post) the functions:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder 
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
```

That is most likely where your issue lies.

Comment: thanks a lot. but I don't see where the issue could be in my coder methods (i've included them in my updated post). it works for me 100% and at all times, so I simply don't understand why some users have trouble with it and their data being deleted etc.

Comment: I've updated my question with the type of variables I am using. THanks so much for your help -- it's greatly appreciated. It's so depressing to hear that people are loosing data...

Comment: Can you reproduce their issue?  Do you have any reproduction steps for this bug?

Comment: Unfortunaly I can't reproduce their issue - otherwise I would have solved it. One problem might have been that I only saved myLibrary.dat in - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application... so I guess that caused some people to loose their data. But it never happened in my case. So hopefully the issue is solved when I save myLibrary.dat every time the user has changed it. Thanks for your hep!

Comment: Sounds like that was most likely your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Users are able to access the documents directory under iOS5 and under any version if they use jailbroken phones. Save your files to `~/Library/Application Support/appname` instead.

```
NSMutableString *path = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
[path appendString: [paths objectAtIndex: 0]];
[path appendString: @"/YOURAPPNAME"];
```

edit

The code you posted works fine and there shouldn't be any problems if your array contains data types supported by NSCoding. As a matter of style, I would use a constant as key to avoid silly typos in the keys. eg: `NSString *const kTitleName = @"kTitleName";` above your @implementation section.

Comment: yes, if some one could comment, that would be helpful. i suppose people don't like data being saved in the application support folder? don't know!

Comment: Sigh, any reason for this -2? There is no problem using NSKeyedArchiver with supported objects like mutable arrays (unlike someone posted earlier, now deleted), or bools as NSNumber. So unless your non posted code is wrong (you should unit test it) I have to guess someone has been messing with your conf files.

Comment: Thanks Jano. Still waiting for people to explain why they down voted. When you say "array contains data types supported by NSCoding", do you mean that I should only put e.g. NSStrings or Integers into the NSMutableArray tabTitles, right? It's so frustrating not knowing where the bug comes from... and people loosing data because of my app is a very disturbing thought.

Comment: Yes, any of the types specify by NSCoding methods, or any value Foundation object is supported. Specifically there is no errors in the code you posted. If you release versions of your app with different archive contents you should be able to read the old format. The Archives and Serialization guide has some tips on that, but it's just common sense. If you are desperate you could use a crash reporter like QuincyKit (on github) to send yourself some logs with what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, NSKeyedArchiver is a better solution than NSUserDefaults, considering you are storing app data rather than simple default settings.

Regarding your data loss issue...

Users could lose data if the app crashes between the time they enter data and you successfully invoke `saveLibraryDat`.  You might try something like Crashlytics to monitor end-user app crashes.

Users could also lose data if `succeed` in `saveLibraryDat` was false.  Replace `// do something` with meaningful error handling.  Maybe there is no room left on the device to save the data.